# In Rust, is there a way to attach a "validity check" to a returned mutable reference?

Tags: rust, constraints, mutable-reference

I am defining a map structure:

```
struct Point { x: isize, y: isize };

enum MapItem { Pipe, Ground, Start };

struct Map {
    map: Vec<Vec<MapItem>>>,
    start: Option<Point>,
}
```

I have implemented `Index` and `IndexMut` on the Map to support `Map[Point]` operations.
However, the map has constraints around the `Start` map item:

- Only one `Start` map item may be defined in the map.
- When a map item is changed from anything else to `Start`, the `map.start` field is set to `Some(location)`.
- When a map item is changed from `Start` to anything else, the `map.start` field is set to `None`.

I don't know how to maintain these constraints while implementing `IndexMut`.  Is there any way to add a validity constraint to the `&mut MapItem` returned by IndexMut, or do I have to remove the IndexMut implementation and just add a `set(location, item)` method to the base implementation of Map?

Comment: You cannot do that. The best you can do is to have a `set_at(&mut self, Point)` method. Or rethink your design: for example, you can find the start location when requested instead of remembering it (although this is O(N) instead of O(1)).

Comment: IMO indexing should generally be avoided anyway, except when slicing. This is because when the item isn't found, there is no way to communicate that and so a panic is required to handle the failure case. I think explicit panics are nearly always better (`.get(_).unwrap()` for example). (Slicing is the exception because in the failure case, an empty slice can be returned.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By jumping through a lot of interior-mutability-hoops, you can do that. That'd require a lot of code, just to be able to write `mymap[mypoint] = ...` instead of `mymap.set_point(...)` - most likely not worth the trouble.

The problem is that `std::ops::IndexMut` shares it's `Output`-type with `std::ops::Index`, and `std::ops::IndexMut::index_mut()` is defined to return a `&mut Self::Output`. Since you *have* to return a mutable reference from `IndexMut`, you can't actually return some proxy-object that does the enforcement after the fact - there is no way to observe what happened after you gave out that `&mut`-reference.

Comment: You don't need interior mutability to do that with a method. And interior mutability won't help you to do that with indexing. In short, there is absolutely no reason to use interior mutability here.